# Go / Revel : using / importing modified version of package an external package?

Tags: git, github, go, revel

Here is a thing I don't understand.

I "go get" a go package on github. Then, I wanted to modify it. So, I forked it and change the name.

Then, "go get" once more, with my new repo name.

I changed my import lines and then : "revel run". My app was working. And since I removed all the older package files, I was sure my app was running my fork.

But, if I just add this line : fmt.Println("executing: ", sqlStatement) the console / term will never show my sqlStatement or even the word "executing".

However it does show the others "fmt.Println" that was already here in the original package.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try `go get -u` to pull updates, or just `go install` (with `-a` to force rebuilding everything). Go `get` and `install` don't rebuild packages if they haven't changed.

Comment: Still no effect... :-(

Comment: Other things to try; check everything that's being built with the `-x` option, invoke `get`/`install` with a full import path, and make sure there are no symlinks in your GOPATH.